# How to mock navigation in prism?

Tags: unit-testing, navigation, mocking, prism

I started to use Prism a few days ago.

I want to unit test my view models. The first test I'm trying to write is the following : When a command in the MasterDetailPage is executed, verify that the navigation occured.

I guess that I have to mock the navigation service.

Any hints on the best way to achieve this ?

Thanx !

Comment: Try looking that the unit tests in the [Prism source](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/Source), and see how they do it.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice